# Multiple Toolbar layouts for different fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have adopted the "one activity, multiple fragments" way of defining layouts for my Android (Xamarin) application. All views (fragments) share the same `BottomNavigationView` managed by `MainActivity` that adds each fragment to the same `FrameLayout`. But, as some fragments need to define their own `AppBarLayouts`, to for example create a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, I can not just create a `FragmentTransaction` and put those fragments in the same `FrameLayout` container, as the `Toolbar` is part of the Activity's layout and thus not managed by the fragments. It would also seem counterproductive having to add and manage a `Toolbar` for each Fragment.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Having a `FrameLayout` for each variation and then show/hide
  accordingly (in layout for `MainActivity`) when making a
  `FragmentTransaction`.
- Use a fullscreen `DialogFragment` to show contents
  above the active fragment.
- Convert the "offending" fragment into an
  `Activity` (makes it hard to handle the `BottomNavigationView`).

**`MainActivity` currently looks like this (with some details omitted):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_nav" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**appbar_main layout** (used by MainActivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- logo layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**appbar_collapsing layout** (for example used to show a profile page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@drawable/toolbar_app_bg"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ffimageloading.views.ImageViewAsync
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />

        <ffimageloading.views.ImageViewAsync
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProfile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The `appbar_main` layout provided above is quite simple and also the primary way of showing the Toolbar. `appbar_collapsing` differs from the main layout in that the Toolbar is nested within a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to make it collapsible when scrolling while also collapsing two ImageView.

Any examples and advaree is much appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In fragments with bottom layout with changing needs for toolbars.
After testing different methods i concluded with this:

```
 private void createMenus(Toolbar actionBarToolBar, @MenuRes int menu){
        ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setSupportActionBar(actionBarToolBar);
        actionBarToolBar.setTitle("");
        actionBarToolBar.inflateMenu(menu);
    }
```

Call this method here:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        createMenus(mToolbar,R.menu.profile_menu);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //add fragments to adapter
        //...

        return mRootView;
    }
```

Then override this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: Is your actionBarToolbar coming from Fragment? Would that cause that fragment to leak?